# Detect the Orientation of Phone

Tags: android, kotlin, sensors

I want to detect the orientation of phone to rotate the frame from camera, then my pose-estimation can inference this rotated image correctly.

Ex: Someone stands in front of my phone and I put my phone horizontally, then I want to rotate this image to be vertical before inference. Because the model just can catch the person in vertical.

I has tried this:
var orientation = resources.configuration.orientation

But this only works when Screen's Auto-rotate is on and I don't want this.
I don't my app is rotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         val orientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(activity) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                val defaultPortrait = 0
                val upsideDownPortrait = 180
                val rightLandscape = 90
            val leftLandscape = 270
                when {
                    isWithinOrientationRange(orientation, defaultPortrait) -> {} 
                    isWithinOrientationRange(orientation, leftLandscape) -> {} 
                    isWithinOrientationRange(orientation, upsideDownPortrait) -> {} 
                    isWithinOrientationRange(orientation, rightLandscape) -> {} 
                }
            }

           private fun isWithinOrientationRange(
               currentOrientation: Int, targetOrientation: Int, epsilon: Int = 10
           ): Boolean {
               return currentOrientation > targetOrientation - epsilon
                    && currentOrientation < targetOrientation + epsilon
           }
        }
        orientationEventListener.enable()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!! 
I try to add your code to https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/PosenetActivity.kt
I add "orientationEventListener.enable()" in onStart().
Also, I add
"backgroundThread2 = HandlerThread("orientationEventListener").also { it.start() }"
"backgroundHandler2 = Handler(backgroundThread2!!.looper)"
in startBackgroundThread().
But activity seems to be null.

Comment: And I also replace "activity" with "this@PosenetActivity.activity", "this@PosenetActivity.context" , "this.activity" and "this.context". All of them are null.

Comment: @Anthony I didn't go into details with the Github link that you've sent, but In my app I place the code snippet inside the Fragment's `onCreateView()` method. And the hosting Activity orientation is set in the Manifest to `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`